# Can I prevent trespass through (for example) my garden?

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, real-estate

Does the Torah give me the right to stop other people using (for example) my garden as a short-cut between two places?

If I try to prevent this trespass, am I to be criticised (say for withholding a good from others)?

Comment: Why would they have the right to use your property?

Comment: זה נהנה וזה לא חסר  and/or   הזק ראיה אין שמו היזק       I don't know

Comment: related: Talmud Eruvin 53B - http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=53b&format=pdf: "רבי יהושע בן חנניה מימי לא נצחני אדם חוץ מאשה תינוק ותינוקת...תינוקת מאי היא פעם אחת הייתי מהלך בדרך והיתה דרך עוברת בשדה והייתי מהלך בה אמרה לי תינוקת אחת רבי לא שדה היא זו אמרתי לה לא דרך כבושה היא אמרה לי ליסטים כמותך כבשוה"

Comment: Does it matter if your property is in Israel?

Comment: I would certainly like to know the law outside of Israel (as well as in Israel).

Comment: Another angle: Once your garden has become a popular path, then you may no longer stop people walking there. So the sooner you stop them the better.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Do you have a source for that please?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok - It's a Mishaa in Bava-Batra Ch. 6:7 which corresponds to Daf 99b. Codified by the Rambam in Nizkei-Mamon 13:27 and by the Shulchan Aruch in Choshen HaMishpat 377. See the Pischei-Teshuva ibid as to the various opinions whether it applies to a path smaller than 16 Amot. (I.e. do we follow the Rambam on this.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann That's an answer. Please consider posting it as such.

Comment: Similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/98428/170